# discord.js RangeError [MESSAGE_CONTENT_TYPE]: Message content must be a non-empty string

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

```
const { Client }  = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({intents:32767})
const { token } = require('./config.json')
var timer = 0

setInterval(
    () => timer ++,
    1000
);

client.once('ready',()=>{
    console.log("bot ready")
})

client.on('messageCreate' , message=>{
    if(message.content == "!uptime"){
        console.log(timer)
        message.reply(timer)
    }
})

client.login(token)
```

error log : RangeError [MESSAGE_CONTENT_TYPE]: Message content must be a non-empty string.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the content you want to send is a `number` while [`reply`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reply) only accepts a `string` (or an `object`).

Try to convert your `timer` variable to a string:

```js
message.reply(timer.toString())
```

Or:

```js
message.reply(`${timer}`)
```